# Anchor vwap 1 hour before signal. Pine Script Tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I would like to anchor a vwap who start 1 hour before a signal but vwap start at brKI and not 1 hour before... can someone help me please ?

```
brkI = price>=bSup60 and price>=bSup120 and low>=bSup30 ? bSup30 : na

milliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 1 * 1  // millisecs * secs * min * hours * days
start = brkI ? time - milliseconds : na

sumSrc = price * volume
sumVol = volume
sumSrc := start ? sumSrc : sumSrc + sumSrc[1]
sumVol := start ? sumVol : sumVol + sumVol[1]

plot(sumSrc / sumVol, title="VWAP", color=color.blue, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this cannot be done in Pine, because it would require to change the historical values of a series, which is not allowed.